# For-loop implementation of a key for an object HTML

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop

I have a queryset full of weather objects and I need to loop through a custom array to extract specific weather metrics in each of the weather objects in an HTML template for a Django application.

detail.html

```
<table>
<tr>
   {% for weather_object in weather_objects %}
      {% for variable in variable_list %}  ## variable_list = ['temp', 'humidity']
          <td>{{weather_object.variable}}</td>
      {% endfor  %}

   {% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

Views.py

```
context = {'weather_objects': weather_objects,
           'variable_list': variable_list}

return render(
    request,
    'webapp/detail.html',
    context=context
)
```

There could be better ways to do this, but honestly, I'm really stumped here. Why can't I loop through the variable list and extract data from weather_object? It's specifically 'weather_object.variable' that just acts nonexistent.

I can do it manually, I can write specifically

```
<td>{{weather_objects.temp}}</td>
```

or

```
<td>{{weather_objects.humidity}}</td>
```

but I can't automate it in a for a loop. Why?? I have verified that the variables in the variable list are correct and should work. Could it be because the variable is only a string substitute?

Comment: because `{{ weather_object.variable }}` will look for `weather_object.variable` (so an attributed *named* `variable`), and `weather_object['variable']`, not for `weather_object.temp` or `weather_object['temp']` if `'temp'` is assigned to `variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write:

```
{{weather_object.variable }}
```

it aims to obtain the attribute *named* `variable` from the `weather_object`, and if that fails, it will try to use `weather_object['variable']`. The fact that there is a variable named `variable` does not matter. That would also be very unstable: imagine that you assign a variable named `humidity = 'temp'`. It would easily break the application since now all `item.humidity`s all of a sudden should use `item.temp` instead. That would be bad code design.

However a template should *not* implement business logic: it should only implement rendering logic. It is the view that needs to pass data in an accessible way to the view.

You for example can construct a list of lists for your `weather_objects` with:

```
variable_list = ['temp', 'humidity']
weather_data = [
    [getattr(datum, v) for v in variable_list]
    for datum in wheather_objects
  ]
context = {'weather_data': weather_data }

return render(
    request,
    'webapp/detail.html',
    context=context
)
```

and then render this as:

```
<table>
  {% for weather_object in weather_data %}
    <tr>
      {% for item in weather_object %}
          <td>{{ item }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```